# Automatic flexible deployment software

Tags: linux, open-source, automation

Looking for open source software (not SAAS) that can deploy projects to different endpoints via protocols such as SSH, FTP, Amazon S3 etc.

More specifically:

1. I will compile static websites and build them using my build process
2. Drop these into a directory that is monitored, or maybe run a bunch of custom shell commands
3. Deploy these websites to different places using different protocols per project. Some will be deployed using SSH, GIT, FTP etc. So I need it to be flexible.

Is there such a platform complete, that is not too high learning curve?

Comment: Have you tried [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [saltstack](http://saltstack.com/) for tasks similar to this.  The learning curve may be a little higher than what you want...but I didn't think it was worse than any other deployment software.

A good place to get started is [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/walkthrough.html).

Another great thing about saltstack is that their IRC is super active, and people are there asking and answering questions a decent amount.  If you need help understanding something, and you've actually googled it first (of course), then you can find their IRC and get help there.

Hope this helps.